# LAB: Sorting TV Shows (dictionaries and lists)

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have used Pycharm to help me correct this issue. I have tried to put a specific range. I was considering user count +=1 every time something was print but couldn't get it into the code without getting an error.
my output

```
    07: Rules of Engagement; Medium; Lux Video Theatre
    08: Mama; Barney Miller; Castle
    10: Will & Grace; Smallville; Modern Family; Friends
    11: Cheers; The Jeffersons
    12: Murder, She Wrote; NYPD Blue
    14: Dallas; Bonanza
    15: ER
    20: Gunsmoke; Law & Order; Law & Order: Special Victims Unit
    30: The Simpsons
''''
expected output

    7: Rules of Engagement; Medium; Lux Video Theatre
    8: Mama; Barney Miller; Castle
    10: Will & Grace; Smallville; Modern Family; Friends
    11: Cheers; The Jeffersons
    12: Murder, She Wrote; NYPD Blue
    14: Dallas; Bonanza
    15: ER
    20: Gunsmoke; Law & Order; Law & Order: Special Victims Unit
    30: The Simpsons
'''
```

''''

```
file = input() #user file input
with open(file) as f: #open file 
    data = f.readlines()
dict_info = {}
for i in range(0, len(data)-1, 2): 
    season = data[i].strip()
    name = data[i+1].strip()
    if(season in dict_info):
        dict_info[season].append(name)
    else:
        dict_info[season] = [name]

#OUTPUT KEYS
keys = list(dict_info.keys()) #will list the dictionary keys
keys.sort() #will sort the keys from min to max
with open('output_keys.txt', 'w') as f:
    for key in keys:
        names = '; '.join(name for name in dict_info[key]) #will print the name with number 
        f.write(str(key)+': '+names+"\n")
names = [] #Dictionary value
for item in dict_info: #will add name to dict
    for name in dict_info[item]:
        names.append(name) 

#OUTPUT TITTLE
names.sort() #sort names from min to max
with open('output_titles.txt', 'w') as f: #open the file
    for name in names: #will write name plus a new line
        f.write(name+'\n')
```

Comment: It looks like you are doing a whole lot of work you don't have to here.  Perhaps if you were to post some of the raw data someone might help you find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

In Line 6, you should assign the variable season as an integer.

```
season = int(data[i].strip())
```

This will remove the 0s before the 7 and 8 in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I just wrote up for this lab. This program is typically longer than others I post on here, but this lab can be intimidating to beginner programmers who have not been introduced to features like pretty print. Therefore, I tried to simplify each requirement using what has been learned so far in their class. Dictionaries are a mapping type, but the lab asks you to produce a dictionary that is both mapping and sequential.

```
# Dictionary to store channels and their respective shows.
my_dict = {}
# Dictionary that results from sorting my_dict.
sorted_dict = {}
# A list used to sort the titles for test 3.
sorted_list = []

# Opening the file declared from input in read-only.
f1 = open(input(), 'r')

# contents is a list of strings where the first element is the first line of input and so forth.
contents = f1.readlines()

# Close the file as soon as it is no longer needed.
f1.close()

# A step of 2 is used so an out-of-range index error does not occur at EOF.
for i in range(0, len(contents), 2):
    # Through each iteration, key is assigned with the numbers within the file.
    # Using int() eliminates the '\n' you would normally see in output involving each line.
    key = int(contents[i])
    # value is the line after each number in the file. Example: "Dallas" would be value if key is 14.
    # This is because [i + 1] grabs the line following the current line in the iteration the loop is in.
    # strip() removes the newline similar to int()
    value = contents[i+1].strip()
    
    # Add value to sorted_list so it can be sorted at the end of the loop.
    sorted_list.append(value)
    
    # If a key already exists in my_dict.
    # In the example: this statement will activate when the 2nd iteration of '20' reaches this point.
    if key in my_dict:
        # In the example: my_dict[key] = 'Gunsmoke' and value = 'Law & Order'.
        # Therefore, 20 is assigned with 'Gunsmoke; Law & Order'.
        my_dict[key] = my_dict[key] + '; ' + value
    # If a key does not exist in my_dict AKA the key only occurs once in the file:
    else:
        my_dict[key] = value

# Sort the list after the loop in ascii order.
sorted_list.sort()

# In example: sorted(my_dict) = ['10', '12', '14', '20', '30'].
# sorted_key iterates through each element in numerical order.
for sorted_key in sorted(my_dict):
        # In example: sorted_dict[10] = my_dict[10] = "Will & Grace"
        # Remember to use the str() feature to prepare the key for being written on a file.
        sorted_dict[str(sorted_key)] = my_dict[sorted_key]

# Opens "output.keys.txt" in write-only.
f2 = open("output_keys.txt", 'w')

# The for loop iterates through each key-value pair in sorted_dict for proper writing formatting to the file.
for key, value in sorted_dict.items():
        
    # We do not need to convert any variables to a string, but we must use a newline at the end of each write.
    # Do not be afraid to test your output with a print() statement before writing.
    f2.write(key + ": " + value + '\n')

# Closes the file after being written.
f2.close()

# Opens "output.titles.txt" in write-only.
f3 = open("output_titles.txt", 'w')

# Iterates through every value of sorted_list
for value in sorted_list:
    f3.write(value + '\n')

# Closes the file after being written.
f3.close()
```

When I first did this lab long ago, I kind of cheated and output the contents of my dictionary in order rather than sorting my dictionary. I was lucky my professor showed me mercy and gave me full points regardless.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work and get the full 10/10. I kept forgetting to strip the extra numbers when writing my code, but I figured it out in the    `output_file += d_key.lstrip('0') + ': '` line that the strip was needed.

```
    file_name = input()
user_file = open(file_name)
input_list = user_file.readlines()


my_diction = {}

for index in range (len(input_list)):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        diction_key = input_list[index].strip('\n')
        if diction_key not in my_diction:
            my_diction[diction_key] = []
    else:
        my_diction[diction_key].append(input_list[index].strip('\n'))




sorted_keys = sorted(my_diction.keys())
output_file = ''
tv_show_list = []

for d_key in sorted_keys:
    output_file += d_key.lstrip('0') + ': '
    for tvshow in my_diction[d_key]:
        output_file += tvshow + '; '
        tv_show_list.append(tvshow)
    output_file = output_file[:-2] + '\n'
print(output_file)
file = open("output_keys.txt", "w")
file.write(output_file)
file.close()


tv_show_list.sort()

sorted_list = ''
for tv_show in tv_show_list:
    sorted_list += tv_show + '\n'
print(sorted_list)
file = open("output_titles.txt", "w")
file.write(sorted_list)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my LAB 4.9.1 for this particular exercise, the expected output was in reverse order. This is the code I used to complete the assignment for full credit by reversing the sort order for the keys and name variables:

```
file = input() # file input
with open(file) as f: #open file
    data = f.readlines()
dict_info = {}
for i in range(0, len(data)-1, 2):
    season = int(data[i].strip())
    name = data[i+1].strip()
    if(season in dict_info):
        dict_info[season].append(name)
    else:
        dict_info[season] = [name]

#OUTPUT KEYS
keys = list(dict_info.keys()) #will list the dictionary keys
keys.sort() #will sort the keys
with open('output_keys.txt', 'w') as f:
    for key in reversed(keys): #reverses the sort order for output
        names = '; '.join(name for name in dict_info[key]) #will print the name with number
        f.write(str(key)+': '+names+"\n")
names = [] #Dictionary value
for item in dict_info: #will add name to dict
    for name in dict_info[item]:
        names.append(name)

#OUTPUT TITLE
names.sort() #sort names
with open('output_titles.txt', 'w') as f: #open the file
    for name in reversed(names): #reverses the sort order for output
        f.write(name+'\n') #will write name plus a new line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_name = input()
tv_shows = {}


with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
  info = f.readlines()
  
  for i in range(0, len(info), 2):
    season =info[i].strip()
    show = info[i+1].strip()
    if season in tv_shows:
      tv_shows[season].append(show)
    else:
      tv_shows[season] = [show]

keys = list(tv_shows.keys())
keys.sort(reverse=True)

with open('output_keys.txt', 'w') as f:
  for key in keys:
    names = '; '.join(x for x in tv_shows[key])
    f.write(f'{str(int(key))}: {names}\n')

names = []
for i in tv_shows:
  for j in tv_shows[i]:
    names.append(j)
names.sort(reverse=True)


with open('output_titles.txt', 'w') as f:
  for i in names:
    f.write(f'{i}\n')
```

Comment: my solution to the problem after a bunch of research :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).